# Crossrider extension not installing on IE

Tags: crossrider

I have developed crossrider extension, but when I try to install that extension in Internet explorer (version 8), it gives me virus alert and antivirus does not allow it to install. I also tried installing demo extension present on crossrider site. (http://crossrider.com/download/12575) It also gave same virus alert (adware) and did not install .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, warnings such as these ARE NOT viruses or worms, they are merely a message that the AV solution generates to say "we consider this software suspicious or suspect" and it MAY (MAY being the operative word) contain viruses. Now, there are many possible reasons why installers MAY be considered suspicious, usually along the lines of the software doesn't have a lot of downloads and is therefore untrusted, or other such reasons. For this reason, AV solution provide a mechanism to add an exception to ignore such incidents, so that installers can run without further warning. The other option is to simply disable the AV solution during the install and when it detects it later, allow the instance and AV solution will  automatically create an exception.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Asking users to disable their anti virus while install something?? I cannot ask every user to do so :(